# Remove lines in a ListPicker or hide them using styles

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Is there any way to lose the lines on a ListPicker? See my image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android I know,

go here `app\App_Resources\Android\src\main\res\values\styles.xml` then under `name="AppThemeBase"` add

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/transparent</item>
```

here is the `color.xml`

```
<color name="transparent">@android:color/transparent</color>
```

That's all, For `ios` also I hope same thing will be there.

Comment: Wow, cool. Is there a way to apply it to just this listpicker? I have one on another page that I don't want to remove the lines.

Comment: @bradrice try applying theme to only that list picker. something like android:theme="@style/Theme.RedPlanetTheme" I don't know whether it will work. But try something was there.

Comment: I've tried everything. I wonder if nativescript doesn't allow android styles except for top level theme? I can't seem to figure out how to style a single view.

Comment: It is possible using the ElementRef. I finally discovered what can be done to remove those lines in Android.pickerLoaded(args){
        let thispicker = <ListPicker>args.object;
        thispicker.nativeView.setSelectionDividerHeight(0); }